# Error Parsing XML while running Tomcat Server 9. Project Spring 3.2 along with hibernate ORM

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Console log : while running the server. I have tried deleting `.m2` folder jars so that they are not corrupted but still the same error. Is it because I'm running Spring 3.2 with Tomcat 9.0 and Java 8?

I'm using MySQL as database and no table is also created.

```
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:15 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:15 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Aug 14 22:19:15 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 42 more

Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5197)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 42 more

Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Fitness] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Aug 14 22:19:15 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Aug 14 22:19:15 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4782)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Aug 14 22:19:15 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4782)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4782)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5419)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)

Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 14, 2017 10:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6514 ms
```

**web.xml** :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

Below will be servlet mapping...

**jpaContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fitnesstracker?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

­

Comment: Do you have an applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF folder? Please share its content if present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

with:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

because you need the definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters, Spring will search by contextConfigLocation context-param.

See [ContextLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html) documentation:

> Processes a "contextConfigLocation" context-param and passes its value
>   to the context instance, parsing it into potentially multiple file
>   paths which can be separated by any number of commas and spaces, e.g.
>   "WEB-INF/applicationContext1.xml, WEB-INF/applicationContext2.xml".
>   Ant-style path patterns are supported as well, e.g.
>   "WEB-INF/*Context.xml,WEB-INF/spring*.xml" or
>   "WEB-INF/**/*Context.xml". If not explicitly specified, the context
>   implementation is supposed to use a default location (with
>   XmlWebApplicationContext: "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml").

Check if your jpaContext.xml is correct location in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

copy servlet-config.xml to web-inf and change name to mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/jpaContext.xml ,
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,    
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```